# : Error: Member not found: 'fadeDuration'

Tags: ios, flutter

Hello while trying to run my flutter iOS app on device im getting following error

SchedulerBinding.instance!
^
: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
../…/selection/overlay.dart:141

- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
  package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:1
  if (SchedulerBinding.instance!.schedulerPhase ==
  ^
  : Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
  ../…/selection/overlay.dart:143
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
  package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:1
  SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback(_markNeedsBuild);
  ^
  : Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
  ../…/selection/overlay.dart:193
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
  package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:1
  if (SchedulerBinding.instance!.schedulerPhase ==
  ^
  : Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
  ../…/selection/overlay.dart:195
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('../../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
  package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:1
  SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback(_markNeedsBuild);
  ^
  : Error: Member not found: 'fadeDuration'.
  ../…/selection/handle_overlay.dart:60
  duration: TextSelectionOverlay.fadeDuration, vsync: this);
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  Failed to package /Users/name/Desktop/Project/application/nameofapliaction/ios/...
  Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
  note: Using new build system
  note: Planning
  note: Build preparation complete
  note: Building targets in dependency order
  note: Removed stale file '/Users/name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bwvfmwkvjuzlddcmattnzdbblkrd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app'
  Result bundle written to path:
  /var/folders/0w/y0t7gyj53sld2zl56qqjmyzh0000gn/T/flutter_tools.mvIp8G/flutter_ios_build_temp_direh9ulh/temporary_xcresult_bundle
  Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on iPhone.
Exited (sigterm)

I really have no idea what the hack this means . So hoper anyone can help

Comment: Can you include your code-snipppet?

Comment: Thanks for reply sorry indont know even which one i should include . Is there any specially line which you need ?

Comment: I can give a try if I am able reproduce the same error, Does it only  happen on iPhone?

Comment: i dont tested yet on android. But if it means to give you the full code that’s probably not possible. So how you wamt to reproduce the error ?

Comment: need a widget, you can check [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Yes thats provably the issue but as i said its a giant project so no idea what i could send you. But also need to say this errors happens after switching from stable to master

Comment: try with `flutter clean` and rebuilding the app

Comment: I tried did not work

Comment: Anyways I switched back to stable channel theres everything working probably simpler than searching for more hours for a solution.

Comment: I faced the same. In my case issue was fixed after switching from the flutter beta channel to the stable channel by using the following commands:
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade